# How can I tie input checkbox to Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I can't bind my checkbox result to Javascript code. How can I do this correctly? The script doesn't react to this.

**application.js**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
 function setCheckbox() {
    $('.check').on('click', function complete(){
      alert("alert");
    }) }
})
```

**view file**

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="<% article.complete %>" class='check' data-remote="true" >
```

Comment: You just defined a function `setCheckbox` but you didn't execute it, either execute it after declare or just remove the that `setCheck` and left the `$('.check').on(...` part.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I'm curious why is this script invoked only one time? And I have to refresh the page to get alert again.

Comment: I'm not sure, the alert works normal on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fnnm2w6y/), maybe you can put  the code on jsfiddle so we can check?

Comment: @fuyushimoya I was mistaken. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a change event instead of a click

```
$('.check').on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: what does change event exactly do?

Comment: It looks for a change in value, and fuyushimoya is right about the function you wrapped your jquery in, it isn't being called so it won't do anything. Either call the function or take it out of `setCheckbox()`

Comment: Ok, let it be. But how the checkbox option should look then for that event?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Well, the input should be like you have it, except your injected ruby is only being evaluated and not printed as html, you need an equal sign to render the article.complete `<%= article.complete %>`.  Next, If you are wanting this to update your article, you would need to put it in a form. On that form you would put 'remote: true' and would then need to have a js format that you respond to in your update method in the controller. I would read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to gain a better understanding of how to accomplish what you want